# How can I know my English level?

Tags: english

I learn English everyday. How can I know that I am making progress or not?

Comment: Presumably you will gradually find it easier to understand what people are saying or writing in English.

Comment: I wonder if this would be better on Meta., Or perhaps [languagelearning.se]  ...  You should give more details about your situation.  Are you at school? at college.  Do you have a teacher? A book? An app? Do you have money to spend on a test?